# jQuery Mousedown and Mouseover issue

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have written a jQuery function to bind `mouseover` event on `mousedown` to get the effect of click and drag to select td's. I have 10 td's in a table row. The problem with this code is, If I want to select td's from 1 to 5 and I do a `mousedown` on td1 and `mouseover` till td5, td1 does not get selected (I am checking/unchecking a checkbox) instead it gets selected from td2 to td5. How do I fix it?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
$("#custom-interval-tbl td").mousedown(function() {
     $('#custom-interval-tbl td').bind('mouseover',function(){
            if($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                       $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "");
                       $(this).css({background:"white"});
            } else {
                       $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "checked");
                       $(this).css({background:"#6D7B8D"});
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: As an aside, you could/should use http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ instead of setting the attribute to `""`

Comment: As an aside, you could/should use [api.jquery.com/prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `removeAttr` or `attr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning the `mouseover` event, it is never activated by the one where the mouse is already down. (Since the mouse is ALREADY over, it will never be called.)

You can force this to be called on the TD you already have selected.

```
$("#custom-interval-tbl td").mousedown(function() {
     $('#custom-interval-tbl td').bind('mouseover',function(){
            if($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                       $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "");
                       $(this).css({background:"white"});
            } else {
                       $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "checked");
                       $(this).css({background:"#6D7B8D"});
            }
     });
     $(this).mouseover(); // This part will call the mouseover event on your clicked TD
});
```

Comment: Thanks! all for the quick suggestions